# Trying to get NoteResultSpec example working

Tags: api, evernote

Using Python,

I'd like to search all my notes for a set of tags and then keywords using re.search on the note content.

I'm able to get a basic search for a keyword working using the deprecated `.getNote(guid)` function but I'm unable to successfully get a search with `NoteStore.NoteResultSpec()`

It seems I don't have the correct imports because the error I get is that `NoteStore` doesn't have a `NoteResultSpec()` method.

Can someone share an example of using `NoteResultSpec()` in a search and/or point me to the correct import statement?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteResultSpec), `NoteResultSpec` is data-type not a method.

You have to use [`getNoteWithResultSpec`](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteWithResultSpec) instead.